# Setting up DNS mask with forwarding through SSL

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, certificate, forwarding, mask

My setup is as follows:

User goes to `subdomain.mainsite.org.uk.example`
The site I want to be visible is `www.site2.example`, however they still have to see `subdomain.mainsite.org.uk.example` in the URL address bar.

I have set up a DNS mask with forwarding, so now accessing `subdomain.mainsite.org.uk.example` will keep this as the URL, but show the content from `www.site2.example` as requested.

However, I only have a certificate valid for `www.site2.example`, causing the SSL certificate to be invalid.

How do I go about setting this up so the site is secure? I've tried searching online endlessly but can't find any resources that I fully understand (I'm pretty new to SSL stuff).

Comment: You can not have it both ways: if you want your users to see `subdomain.mainsite.org.uk.example` you need a X509 certificate that matches this name. The certificate for `www.site2.example` is irrelevant in this case. Otherwise any website could impersonate any other one.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a certificate which is configured for both `www.site2.com` and `subdomain.mainsite.org.uk`. You can add more than one domain to a certificate through the use of Subject Alternative Names (SAN). You may also want to consider adding `site2.com`.

Comment: Two separate certificates will also work. (If the clients are so outdated that they don't support SNI, you will need a separate IP address per certificate.)